# no me cargan las imágenes cuando subo el proyecto de nodejs a cyberpanel

Tags: nodejs, servidor

Cordial Saludo

subí proyecto de node.js a mi servidor de cyberpanel y pues funciona todo bien pero las imágenes no me cargan.

yo estoy subiendo el codigo al repositorio de git hub y de hay lo clono en el servidor pero no me funciona y estoy probando subiendolo al administrador de archivos pero no encuentro una URL en la que pueda llamar en el codigo html con el  y ya eh probado con las ruta *nombre del dominio/public_html/images/imagen.jpg* y no me trae la imagen y nose de que otra manera se puden llamar las imagenes

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas posibles causas son las siguientes:

- Si las imágenes se encuentran en una carpeta diferente a la carpeta
  principal del proyecto, es posible que no se haya configurado
  correctamente la ruta de acceso a esa carpeta.
- Si las imágenes se encuentran en la carpeta principal del proyecto,
  es posible que no se haya configurado correctamente el servidor web
  para permitir el acceso a archivos estáticos.